# Cartopy not finding Proj.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartopy, proj

i have installed proj-4.9.1 correctly through the tar.gz and

> ./configure --prefix=/path/to/directory

then "make" and "make install". Nevertheless cartopy tells me

> Proj4 4.9.0 must be installed.

I run the setup script through

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace -I/path/to/cartopy/proj-4.9.1/include -L/path/to/cartopy/proj-4.9.1/lib
```

So do i have to take care of anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply had to add

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pathto/proj-4.9.1/lib/$LIBRARY_PATH
>
> export PATH=/pathto/proj-4.9.1/bin:$PATH

Comment: How do you find this path to proj-4 on linux Ubuntu?

Comment: It's the installation location you choose, if i remember right

Comment: How can I find that location if I can't remember which location I've chosen?

Comment: /usr/local on Unix-like systems